# Analytical Function Of Oracle vs MariaDB

Tags: sql, oracle, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

Currently migrating my Oracle queries to MariaDB 10.4

I have a hard time in analytical function.

> MARIADB Code:

```
select cgi, timestamp, hour, rat_type, dl_tput,
       ntile(24) over (partition by timestamp,rat_type order by dl_tput) as dl_tput_ntiled
from (select cgi, date(timestamp) as timestamp, 
             date_format(timestamp,'%H') as hour, rat_type, avg(avg_mean_down) as dl_tput
      from JUST_TEST_A
      where avg_mean_down is not null
      group by cgi, date(timestamp),date_format(timestamp,'%H'),rat_type
     ) x ;
```

This code works fine, but after validating the output the result from Oracle is different from the result of MariaDB (same data)

My oracle script have this script that I’ve removed in mariadb.

```
select cgi, timestamp, hour, rat_type, dl_tput,
       ntile(24) over (partition by timestamp,rat_type order by dl_tput) as dl_tput_ntiled,
       count(*) over () as dl_tput_cnt
from (...)
```

Does `count(*) over ()` affects my output? What is the alternative query for MariaDB of this analytical function?

Comment: You have `. . . ` in your question for the Oracle code.  However, Oracle does not support the functions used in MariaDB so it is not clear what the subquery is doing.  Also, how different are the results?  How do you know the underlying data is the same?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe that this ... means that the other part is the same as above code.

Comment: @Ace, count(*) over () will work in MariDB

Comment: (. . .) is the same of my subquery in maria

Comment: @VBoka, what is the effect of count(*) over ()?

Comment: @VBoka . . . If it is, it is going to generate a syntax error in Oracle because functions like `date_format()` and `date()` are not supported.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree now, when I was writting the first comment I was not aware of the date functions in the inner select.(not aware=was superficial). Sorry, you are maybe correct from the begining, maybe date functions are the problem. Cheers.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the output from each server, and describe the intent of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this DEMO here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=be74a9fa9059d6b80a8cb10d102355d4

you will find a small example where I have entered some data and there is a query :

```
select pk
       , a
       , b
       , ntile(24) over (partition by a, b  order by pk)
       , count(*) over () as dl_tput_cnt
from t1;
```

In the upper left corner you have a list of different databases that you can choose from. If you choose Oracle for this example or if you choose Maria DB the result will be the same. This is not the guarantee that `count` and `ntile` are not responsible for your different results but please do tell us more about this results:

> but after validating the output the result from Oracle is different
>   from the result of MariaDB (same data)

Maybe this will help more for your case.

**One more thing.**

I think you should check the results you are getting from Maria DB for this query's:

```
SELECT date(timestamp) FROM JUST_TEST_A


SELECT date_format(timestamp,'%H') FROM JUST_TEST_A
```

and compare them with the old results you received from Oracle for Oracle's equivalent functions for date and date_format.

Comment: Hi @Ace, any feedback on this from you ??

Comment: I am happy to hear that. Thanks for the acceptance of the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is an issue with ties.  `ntile()` will split rows with the same groups across different buckets, because its mandate is for each bucket to be the same size.

As an extreme example, if all the values of `dl_tput` were the same, then any value form 1 to 24 could be assigned.

Comment: @Ace . . . `CGI` is not part of the `ntile()` logic,  I don't think that has any impact.